# Signature endpoint with `GET` request

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

It seems there's no way to set the request method for the signature endpoint. Would it be possible to hack around this? I tried following the call stack up to the `ajax.requester.js` file but I can't figure out where the method is set (which is `POST`).

Comment: simply changing this to GET won't work anyway, as the signature requests contain a payload

Comment: yeah I figured, so right now I'm hacking around the signature endpoint, which isn't ideal but it's working for now.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you are [*really* trying to accomplish](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: It's as simple as that, just needed it to be GET because the backend I'm using to provide the signature only accepts GET.